# HTML 5 - how to zoom canvas background image

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am a beginner in HTML 5,

I have written a code for canvas zoom but I dont want to zoom actual canvas but the background image of canvas like in the http://www.customink.com/lab

following is the code which I have written :

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

canvas.setBackgroundImage('images/1front.png', function() {

    canvas.backgroundImageStretch = true;
    canvas.renderAll();
});

var canvasScale = 1;
var SCALE_FACTOR = 1.2;
function zoomIn() {
    // TODO limit the max canvas zoom in

    canvasScale = canvasScale * SCALE_FACTOR;

    canvas.setHeight(canvas.getHeight() * SCALE_FACTOR);
    canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() * SCALE_FACTOR);

    var objects = canvas.getObjects();
    for (var i in objects) {
        var scaleX = objects[i].scaleX;
        var scaleY = objects[i].scaleY;
        var left = objects[i].left;
        var top = objects[i].top;

        var tempScaleX = scaleX * SCALE_FACTOR;
        var tempScaleY = scaleY * SCALE_FACTOR;
        var tempLeft = left * SCALE_FACTOR;
        var tempTop = top * SCALE_FACTOR;

        objects[i].scaleX = tempScaleX;
        objects[i].scaleY = tempScaleY;
        objects[i].left = tempLeft;
        objects[i].top = tempTop;

        objects[i].setCoords();
    }

    canvas.renderAll();
}

// Zoom Out
function zoomOut() {
    // TODO limit max cavas zoom out

    canvasScale = canvasScale / SCALE_FACTOR;

    canvas.setHeight(canvas.getHeight() * (1 / SCALE_FACTOR));
    canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() * (1 / SCALE_FACTOR));

    var objects = canvas.getObjects();
    for (var i in objects) {
        var scaleX = objects[i].scaleX;
        var scaleY = objects[i].scaleY;
        var left = objects[i].left;
        var top = objects[i].top;

        var tempScaleX = scaleX * (1 / SCALE_FACTOR);
        var tempScaleY = scaleY * (1 / SCALE_FACTOR);
        var tempLeft = left * (1 / SCALE_FACTOR);
        var tempTop = top * (1 / SCALE_FACTOR);

        objects[i].scaleX = tempScaleX;
        objects[i].scaleY = tempScaleY;
        objects[i].left = tempLeft;
        objects[i].top = tempTop;

        objects[i].setCoords();
    }

    canvas.renderAll();        
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `drawImage` as user2422324 suggests, but you must use additional arguments to scale the image while drawing it.

In addition, you must scale the background image to a temporary canvas because fabricjs expects an imageURL when setting it's background

Here's how the scaling works:

First, create a temporary canvas and set it's size to the zoom size you desire.  For example to scale the background image to 200% you would do this:

```
tempCanvas.width=myBackgroundImage.width*2.0;
tempCanvas.height=myBackgroundImage.height*2.0;
```

Now use drawImage to both draw the background image to the tempCanvas.  By supplying the last 4 arguments, the image will be scaled to the desired zoom (which is the current tempCanvas size).

```
tempContext.drawImage(myBackgroundImage,

    // the source of the draw will be the full background image
    0,0, myBackgroundImage.width, myBackgroundImage.height,

    // and this causes the full image to be scaled to fit the resized tempCanvas
    0,0, tempCanvas.width, tempCanvas.height
);
```

Then use fabricJS's setBackgroundImage to apply the scaled background.  We can create the imageURL that fabric expects by using tempCanvas.toDataURL():

```
canvas.setBackgroundImage( tempCanvas.toDataURL(), function(){
    canvas.backgroundImageStretch=true;
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Note that `backgroundImageStretch=true` may cause the image to proportionally distort.  Instead, you might want to set backgroundImageStretch=false and set backgroundImageLeft/backgroundImageTop to offset the background image.

Here is a fairly complete, but totally untested starting code:

```
// this is the current scaling factor of the background image
// hint: originally set it at less than full size
//       so it doesn't pixelate when scaled up.
var scaleFactor=.50;

// create a background image object we can later scale
var fullBk=document.createElement("img");
fullBk.onload=function(){
    setBkZoom(scaleFactor);
}
fullBk.src="images/1front.png";

// create a temp canvas used to scale the bk image
var zoomCanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
var zoomCtx=zoomCanvas.getContext("2d");

// scale the bk image and set it as the fabric background
function setBkZoom(scaleFactor){
    // scale the temp zoomCanvas to desired bk size
    // note: changing canvas width automatically clears it
    zoomCanvas.width=fullBk.width*scaleFactor;
    zoomCanvas.height=fullBk.height*scaleFactor;
    // draw a scaled version of fullBk to zoomCanvas
    zoomCtx.drawImage(fullBk,
        0,0,fullBk.width,fullBk.height,
        0,0,zoomCanvas.width,zoomCanvas.height);
    // now use the scaled zoomCanvas to set the fabric background
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(zoomCanvas.toDataURL(),function(){
        // stretch=true may cause your image to distort proportions
        // instead you might want to set backgroundImageLeft/backgroundImageTop 
        // to offset the scaled image
        canvas.backgroundImageStretch=true;
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to store the background image in an `Image` object and then rendering that with `context.drawImage(img,X,Y,Width,Height);`

Introduction: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-size/

Answer (score 0):

Just make two button using html and give them ids zoomin and zoomout and the using jquery yoou can make zoom in and zoom out effect.

html code

```
<a id="zoomIn" title="Zoom In"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>

<a id="zoomOut" title="Zoom Out"><i class="fa fa-search-minus"></i></a>
```

jquery code

```
jQuery('#zoomIn').click(function() {
    //canvas.setZoom(canvas.getZoom() * 1.1 );
    canvas.zoomToPoint(new fabric.Point(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2), canvas.getZoom() * 1.1);
    canvas.drawImage().renderAll();


});
jQuery('#zoomOut').click(function(){
    if (canvas.getZoom() > 1) 
    {
        //canvas.setZoom(canvas.getZoom() / 1.1 );
        canvas.zoomToPoint(new fabric.Point(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2), canvas.getZoom() / 1.1);

    }
});
```